# Eudoxus' theory of proportion

Tags: geometry

Is it true that Eudoxus in his theory of proportions makes use of an infinite process(implicitly or explicitly)?and if so,how?(I have read in two papers that he does but I didn't manage to figure out how)

Comment: What is theory of proportion?

Comment: *proportions. A theory developed by Eudoxus for comparing ratios, avoiding irrationals by using only geometry.

Comment: @samjoe It's an approach to the definition of "linear correlation" introduced by Greek mathematician Eudoxus of Cnidus. In modern days, we'd describe the idea behind it as "a strictly increasing additive function between ordered fields".

Comment: We also remark that the Eudoxian definition of proportionality uses the term “for every
...” to avoid mentioning the infinite process, which is the same as the modern −δ definitions
of limit and continuity today.